# How can I use the equivalent of pandas pivot_table() in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataFrame that i want to pivot.

input_dataframe:

| mdn | top_protocol_by_vol | top_vol | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55555 | AAA | 30 | 1 |
| 55555 | BBB | 20 | 2 |
| 55555 | DDD | 10 | 3 |
| 9898 | JJJ | 30 | 1 |
| 9898 | CCC | 20 | 2 |
| 9898 | FFF | 10 | 3 |
| 2030 | PPP | 30 | 1 |
| 2030 | KKK | 20 | 2 |
| 2030 | FFF | 10 | 3 |

and I want to have something like this

output_dataframe:

| mdn | top_protocol_by_vol_1 | top_protocol_by_vol_2 | top_protocol_by_vol_3 | top_vol_1 | top_vol_2 | top_vol_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2030 | PPP | KKK | FFF | 30 | 20 | 10 |
| 9898 | JJJ | CCC | FFF | 30 | 20 | 10 |
| 55555 | AAA | BBB | DDD | 30 | 20 | 10 |

I know for sure that i cant do soemting like this with Pandas using the code:

```
output_dataframe = input_dataframe.pivot_table(index='mdn', columns=['rank'],aggfunc=lambda x: ''.join(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x,dropna=True).reset_index()
output_dataframe.columns = [''.join('_'.join([str(c) for c in col if c != ""])) for col in output_dataframe.columns.values]
```

How can I achieve the same results with pyspark converting to pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot` function with `first` as aggregate.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = (df.groupby('mdn')
      .pivot('rank')
      .agg(F.first('top_protocol_by_vol').alias('top_protocol_by_vol'),
           F.first('top_vol').alias('top_vol')))
```